# Hive ORDER BY query results in error

Tags: sql, hadoop, parallel-processing, hive

I have this query working:

```
SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid)
FROM rating
GROUP BY movieid
```

But when I try to add the order by I get an error:

```
SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid)
FROM rating
GROUP BY movieid
ORDER BY count(movieid) DESC;
```

[image: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.NullPointerException(null)]

I know that the SQL query works on sqldeveloper.
Since I also needed to subset I created a nested loop (using desc limit didn't work), but this doesn't work either:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid)
FROM rating
GROUP BY movieid
ORDER BY count(movieid) DESC
) 
where ROWNUM <= 200;
```

I mainly just want the order by working and then I'll go to the next step and see if the subset part works. Any ideas why i'm getting a nullpointexception error?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an alias instead:

```
SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid) as cnt
FROM rating
GROUP BY movieid
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Hive (for some inexplicable reason) doesn't allow aggregation functions in the `order by`.  This gets me on about half the queries I write in Hive.  Slowly I'm remembering . . .

Comment: The order by works with the alias, Thanks a lot!!

`SELECT movieid, COUNT(movieid) as cnt

FROM rating

GROUP BY movieid

ORDER BY cnt DESC limit 200;`